# Woocommerce - Display the product category under product title in shop/archive page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add the product's category between the title and the price of each product. As long as I edited the archive-product.php file with codes i found here, nothing seemed to work. I created a copy of the file on the active theme too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' action for this case

```
function product_category_in_shop_loop() {
    global $product;
    $product_id = $product->get_id();
    $cat = wp_get_post_terms($product_id, 'product_cat', array('fields' => 'names'));
    if( !empty($cat[0]) ){
       echo '<p class="catil">'.$cat[0].'</p>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'product_category_in_shop_loop', 40 );
```

code goes to child theme function.php.

Comment: Ahhh i love you dude. Solved the problem! Have a nice one